# Android: app with tab, database changes can be viewed only when closing and reopening app

Tags: android, database, listview

i've got an app made with tab. one tab use a method get_data() (called from another class) to take data from db.

it works fine, but the changes made from another tab or in the tab incriminated (changed like DELETE or UPDATE) can't be seen, example:

i go in the tab (with a listview) with the data taken from db, then i delete a record, then i go to another tab and then i return to the tab with the list.
i see the deleted row.
if i close the app and reopen it, i see the changes.

there's a way to "reload the database"?

here's the code (view.class), reader from a tab:

```
public class Bookmarks extends Activity{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bookmarks);
    final Database info=new Database(this);
    final Timer t = new Timer();
    info.open();
    String data=info.getData();
    final String[] data_array = data.split(",");
    info.close();
    final ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_mia);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data_array);
    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id){
            if(data_array[position].startsWith("http://")){
                Uri uri=Uri.parse((String) data_array[position]);
                Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else{
                alertDialog.setTitle("Content");
                alertDialog.setMessage(data_array[position]);
                alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        }
    });
    listView1.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, final int position, long id) {
            builder.setTitle("Delete")
                .setMessage("Are you sure to remove this entry?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        info.open();
                        info.deleteEntry(position+1);
                        info.close();
                        alertDialog.setTitle("Delete");
                        alertDialog.setMessage("Item deleted successfully!");
                        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                        alertDialog.show();
                        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                            public void run() {
                                alertDialog.dismiss();
                                t.cancel();
                            }
                        },2000);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {}
                })
            .show();
            return false;
        }
    });
}
}
```

and the method called (in db.class):

```
public String getData() {
    String[] columns=new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_CONTENUTO};
    Cursor c=ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE,columns,null,null,null,null,"id");
    String result="";
    int iRow=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iName=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CONTENUTO);
    for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
        result=result+c.getString(iName)+',';
    }
    result=result.substring(0, result.length()-1);
    return result;
}
```

can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I ask why you are doing all that extra processing?  You are querying the cursor, concatenating the results, returnng the concatenated results, and then splitting them again.  That's a bit intensive on the processor.

Why not just use the cursor directly with a SimpleCursorAdapter?  Then you just use `requery()` to refresh the list.

You can do it with the following changes:

```
public class Bookmarks extends Activity{ 
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.bookmarks); 
    final Database info=new Database(this); 
    final Timer t = new Timer(); 
    info.open(); 
    Cursor data=info.getData(); 
    final ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_mia); 
    String[] from = new String[] { db.KEY_CONTENUTO };
    int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data, from, to); 
    listView1.setAdapter(adapter); 

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create(); 
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 
    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){ 
        @Override 
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id){ 
            if(view.getText().toString().startsWith("http://")){ 
                Uri uri=Uri.parse(view.getText().toString()); 
                Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri); 
                startActivity(intent); 
            }else{ 
                alertDialog.setTitle("Content"); 
                alertDialog.setMessage(view.getText().toString()); 
                alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher); 
                alertDialog.show(); 
            } 
        } 
    }); 
    listView1.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){ 
        @Override 
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, final int position, long id) {  
        long rowId = id;
        builder.setTitle("Delete") 
            .setMessage("Are you sure to remove this entry?") 
            .setCancelable(false) 
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) { 
                    info.deleteEntry(rowId); 
                    data.requery();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Delete"); 
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Item deleted successfully!"); 
                    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher); 
                    alertDialog.show(); 
                    t.schedule(new TimerTask() { 
                        public void run() { 
                            alertDialog.dismiss(); 
                            t.cancel(); 
                        } 
                    },2000); 
                } 
            }) 
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {} 
            }) 
        .show(); 
        return false; 
    } 
});
```

} 
}

```
public Cursor getData() { 
    String[] columns=new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_CONTENUTO}; 
    Cursor c=ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE,columns,null,null,null,null,"id"); 
    return c; 
}
```

Comment: just because it's the first time i use database in android, i'm learning it with the help of thenewboston youtube channel.
your posted code return tons of errors...

Comment: Heh, well, without your full code, it wouldn't be an exact fit, you'd need to tailor for what I didn't know/missed.  Not a big deal, I just wanted you to be aware that the way you are doing it will be a bit intensive on the power use.  Ankit's answer shoudl work just fine for you.  Good luck!

Comment: i've integrated your code, now it's without error but one:
view.getText().ToString() it says that getText is not right

Comment: Oh bugger, mis-capitalization.  `view.getText().toString()` (note the change from capital T to lowercase t on the `toString()` portion).  Sorry about that.  Oh, you probably don't need to cast that to (String) either.  I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: no problem, i found this error also in php, case-sensitive!
i'll try this code and see what happen. now, getText isn't right, it ask to change to getContext. and i produce an error like column _id doesn't exist

Comment: Hmm, wrong id... you need to use the `long id` from the `onItemLongClick` parameters, not the `int id` from the dialog.  Set it to some variable and use that in your dialog (you might need to change your delete method to use a long instead of an int too).  I've updated my answer once again.

Comment: apart that getText doesn't exist, the problem is not resolved, and i know because if i remove the 2 onlick, the problem persist

Comment: I'm sorry then, as far as I can tell it should all be working.  I'm at a loss as to what's wrong with it.  `getText()` is a standard method available to TextViews.  See the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText()).  Maybe `view` should be cast to a TextView before use. `Textview viewTemp = (Textview) view;` and then replace `view` in all those calls with `viewTemp`.  If that doesn't solve it, I'm completely out of ideas.

Comment: The `view` returned in the itemclick and longitemclick is the *row* view, and in your case your row layout contains a single TextView.

Comment: yes but here the getText doesn't work, and onclick i read my namespace instead of the content of the item

Comment: resolved calling the content as a string from the db using id.

Answer (score 1):

you should create a method like given below, When you delete or update info in database.  call this method within the same activity it will fetch the data and reload list.

```
   setData() {

    info.open();
    String data=info.getData();
    final String[] data_array = data.split(",");
    info.close();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data_array);
    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
```

P.S:  above code is to give you just an hint that you can basically reload list on deletion or updation of db. it is not a exact solution.

Comment: for tabchangin i think you should call above method from onResume method of activity. i am not sure that it will call on tab change but you can give it  a try